# Make a jquery img cycle animation dissapear

Tags: jquery, background, cycle, fadein, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a Jquery Cycle Plugin to create a fadein background. However I wanted to see if it is possible to make it go away once you open an accordion tab from the menu and appear again once they are all closed. Here is the link to the website so that you have a better idea. 
[WEBSITE](http://www.johnfitzphoto.com/sofi/ALEXA/home.html)

this is the jquery cycle plugin I'm using:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is THE SLIDE (ACCORDION) SRIPT i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.slidecontrol').click(function(){
    $(".display").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
            var $this = $(this);
            var divID = $this.attr("id").replace("slidecontrol_", "slidedisplay_");
            var $div = $('#'+divID);
            if ($div.is(':visible')) {
                $div.slideUp(500);
            } else {
                $div.slideDown(500);
            }
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

Thanks! Sofi

Comment: Good!  Glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding a `$('.slideshow').cycle('pause')` in your `click()` ?

More details here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pause.html

**Edit based on your comments:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var toggleBackground = function() {
    if ($('.display:visible').length) {
        $('.slideshow').fadeOut().cycle('pause');
    } else {
        $('.slideshow').fadeIn().cycle('resume');
    }
}

$('a.slidecontrol').click(function(){
    $(".display").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
    var $this = $(this);
    var divID = $this.attr("id").replace("slidecontrol_", "slidedisplay_");
    var $div = $('#'+divID);
    if ($div.is(':visible')) {
        $div.slideUp(500, toggleBackground);
    } else {
        $div.slideDown(500, toggleBackground);
    }

    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that earlier and it works perfectly, but I just realized I worded my question wrong, :S sorry. I actually want for the background to disappear when you click a tab and then appear again when they are all closed. @LekisS

Comment: ok so I changed the script and it does work perfectly with the fadeout but not with the fade in :S. You can see the website online [website](http://www.johnfitzphoto.com/sofi/ALEXA/home.html) @LekisS

Comment: oh yes sorry... You have to put the "verification" once the SlideUp/SlideDown are done. Let me edit my answer.